# Rails redirect_to rendering but not showing the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest

I'm trying to redirect_to a view from another after some actions inside my controller

My Controller

```
def sendPayment
@jsonParams = cleanParams(params)


@result = HTTParty.post('http://pxxxxxxxxxs'.to_str,
:body => @jsonParams.to_json,
:headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
              'Api-Access-Key' => 'xxxxxxxx',
              'Transaction-Hash' => xxxx } )

 puts @result
 redirect_to payments_response_path(:result => @result)
end
```

In My console I get this message:

```
 Processing by PaymentsController#show as JS
 Parameters: {"id"=>"response"}
 Rendered payments/show.html.erb within layouts/application (0.3ms)
 Completed 200 OK in 33ms (Views: 32.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

But my view is never rendered... Can anyone help?

My Routes:

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
 get 'home/index'

 root 'home#index' 

 resources :home
 resources :payments
 resources :bills
 resources :accounts

 #Payment Custom Routes
 post 'payments/send', to: "payments#sendPayment"
 get 'payments/send', to: "payments#sendPayment"
 post 'payments/remove', to: "payments#deletePayment"
 get 'payments/remove', to: "payments#deletePayment"
 get 'payments/response', to: "payments#responseShow"
 #Bills Custom Routes
 post '/sendBill', to: "bills#sendBill"


 end
```

Comment: What does your responseShow action look like, and what's the name of the view. I guess it's a Rails COC issue.

Comment: My responseShow its just response = params[:response], I do want to show the response in my view response.html.erb, I want to use that same view for others reponses I could get from similar actions in my controller

Comment: redirect_to produces HTTP 301/302 response code, if you see *Completed 200 OK* another action is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Make sure you have `responseShow` method in your controller, and also you have `responseShow.html.erb` in your `views/payments` folder.

2) Try to add `return` immediately after `redirect_to` method inside of your `sendPayment` method:

```
redirect_to payments_response_path(:result => @result)
return
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to troubleshoot two problems at once - I think that's the biggest source of your confusion here. The way a redirect action works is it tells the browser "No, you want this URL instead", and expects *the browser to make a whole new request*; so you should just be troubleshooting that second request in isolation, not mentioning anything about the redirect. If your app is properly structured, it shouldn't matter if the request to the #show action came from a redirect or came just by typing that URL into the browser.

So ignore the stuff about redirects and just focus on: Why isn't my #show action rendering anything? It looks like your logs are telling you there's no errors, so start with your layouts (are they being called? are they displaying on the page properly?) and work inwards from there.

Comment: Okey, but what if I don't want to show my 'show.html.erb' view when I go /payments/remove? I want to show my remove.html.erb, is that possible to customize?